# what kind of models would best fit for my leg dynamic's case?

Tags: drake

#### Background

I am using [this library and `lower_leg_2_parts` branch](https://github.com/dvogureckiy99/quadruped_drake/tree/lower_leg_2_parts) for modeling my robot solo12.

My robot model is loading in Drake from URDF file using `AddModelFromFile` and after that is connecting the controller to the simulated plant.

What is a deformable body ?

- Material: PETG RELAX with the appropriate characteristics.
- Dimensions of the bounding box: x:y:z 10:10:14 mm
- Shape: I'll provide you with appropriate links:

1. [Flexure Joints for Large Range of Motion video from University of Twente (UT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fFH2RHpcTY).
2. [The book: Design and optimization of large stroke flexure mechanisms by Mark Naves](https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/design-and-optimization-of-large-stroke-flexure-mechanisms).
3. [LARGE-STROKE FLEXURE HINGES](https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/30085211/Naves_Mikroniek_2017_3.pdf).

I want modeling something like that, for example:
[image]
[image]
[image]

These are real prototypes:
[image]

Parameter optimization with modeling the nonlinearities all-together I'm performing in [the flexible multibody dynamics software SPACAR](https://www.spacar.nl/wiki/doku.php).

#### Question

I came to several possible ways to solve this problem: **the question is which way is a best** ?

1. I can create rigid part of the robot and 4 flexible leg's parts and then connect their together. We can add rigid bodies via `AddModelFromFile` and deformable body with `RegisterDeformableBody` separately and put them in a single plant. The deformable body can be prepared in two ways:

1.1. Deformable body can be simulated with FEM by `DeformableModel` `PyDrake` class.

**How to connect together `deformable` and `rigid body`? I tried, e.g. `WeldFrames` along with `AddFrame,FixedOffsetFrame`, but I can't get appropriate `bodyB: drake::multibody::Body<double>` argument of the deformable model.**

In the `RegisterDeformableBody` method written **"The body is represented in the world frame"**. As I understand there is no way to connect deformable body to the another robot cause deformable body cannot have it's own frame.

1.2. Deformable body can be modeled using C++ `ForceElement` as mentioned jwnimmer-tri [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19236).

2. I can model leg as amount of joints, connected like snake's spine with small angle constraints. The problem here is that when I modeled lower leg consisted of 3 links and 2 joints (they are fixed), my leg fell into resonant undamped oscillations.
   [image]
3. Make a bridge between `PyChrono` and `Drake` and use `PyChrono` for modeling deformable bodies.

#### Drake Version

the latest from master branch of drake's repository

#### What operating system are you using?

Ubuntu 20.04

#### What installation option are you using?

compiled from source code using CMake

#### P.S.

I am already studied the example `deformable_torus.ipynb` and learned how to simulate deformable bodies, but there wasn't answer on my question. I went through all the documentation, code, drake's issues, questions here related to Drake and did not find an answer. I say this so that you don't give me cons,then I was banned anyway.

If you required I will provide you instructions for reproducing my program.

Comment: I answered below the question you asked (adding deformable geometry). However, for the goal you're looking for ("springy leg") my intuition says that customizing your joints will be a better modeling choice that using deformable collision geometry. In fact, it might be worthwhile if you open a *new* question that explains exactly what kind of dynamics you're looking to accomplish, and asks what kind of models would best fit those dynamics.

Comment: I can't post more questions, cause of ban.

Comment: In that case, maybe just edit this question add more info explaining what you're trying to accomplish overall.  For example, I wonder if a revolute or prismatic joint with very narrow joint limits would be a better model for deflection within a leg than deformable geometry.

Comment: What is the **physical property** you are trying to model? "springy" doesn't tell us enough. What physics or material property are you trying to simulate? In photos of the solo12 robot online, I only see 2 links for a leg, both actuated.  Maybe if you have a photo or video of the leg you're trying to model that would help too.

Comment: Yea, I preparing it for you. we didn't create physical leg yet, but we created several flexible joints structures, I'll show.

Comment: Much better question now, thanks; I'll ask our dynamicists to reply.

Answer (score 2):

As of today in Drake, the support for deformable models is still incomplete and under development.  So, the process will not be easy (yet).

It does not seem possible currently to specify a deformable geometry via a URDF file.  As in the `deformable_torus.cc` example, you will need to call `RegisterDeformableBody` manually, after making a `GeometryInstance` with your tetrahedral mesh `*.vtk` file.

To remove the non-deformable model, easiest would be to edit (a copy of) your URDF file to remove the proximity geometries you are about to replace.

Comment: Is it possible that I'll create moddel from URDF with `AddModelFromFile` and deformable body with `RegisterDeformableBody` separately and then connect their in one `plant` ?

Comment: Currently you can't specify deformable geometry via asset files. We have plans to support that in the future. Like Jeremy said, the deformable feature is still under development and so documentation etc is not complete yet. The best way to get answers is via stackoverflow and or the Drake developer slack channel.
And yes, you can add rigid bodies via `AddModelFromFile` and deformable body with `RegisterDeformableBody` separately and put them in a single plant.

Comment: I need someone's invitation to the slack channel.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to investigate using Drake with a [linear bushing](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_linear_bushing_roll_pitch_yaw.html) to model extensional, bending, and torsional stiffness and damping.  You may be able to estimate stiffness constants from an existing FEA model.  The documentation provides details on how to estimate damping.

Comment: BTW I like this idea, too.  Our examples of adding the bushing in URDF are very few.  I recommend reading [the parser unit test](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/ec2ee07bae462a5ef64fba1a12361e691c33f17f/multibody/parsing/test/detail_urdf_parser_test.cc#L1304-L1320) to see how to add a bushing via URDF.

Comment: Does it can simulate non-linearity in Stress/Strain dependency, because you know all the materials has hysteresis characteristic, maybe not so significant, but still ?